# Correção com select usando sum dentro de case

Tags: mysql, query

Estou tentando usar o código abaixo:

```
select
case when((sum(valido) / sum(total) * 100) >= 60 then 60 else (sum(valido) / sum(total) * 100) end) i1
from tabela
```

> Erro de sintaxe próximo a 'then 60 else...'

Comment: não entendi, qual é a dúvida?

Comment: oi amigo, desculpa. fiz a alteração do post @RicardoPontual

Comment: Não tem que terminar com END CASE? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado não. o erro está no cálculo. pelo visto terei criar subqueries pra fazer o código que preciso.